# Step SDB has failed error on Tizen App Launch

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-web-simulator

I am trying my hand at Tizen TV App Development and every time i try to launch even the basic template app, I get an error saying:
"Step SDB shell handle failed"
And when I click details:

```
step SDB shell handle failed
Failed to step SDB shell handle 'ls /usr/bin/xwalk-launcher > /tmp/null.deployer 2>&1; echo $? ' command` operation (Return Code:31)
sdb command rejected exception
```

It would be such a huge help if someone here could help out. I checked everywhere. Samsung Developer Forums, the Development Guideline, but couldn't find the solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found the solution, to anyone who wants to know.

Its because of improper security certification. Just follow the steps on this site and you should be good to go!
https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3531/index.html

Comment: feb 27, 2017: Link is broken

Comment: Feb 28, 2018: link still not working. People having the same issue cannot get any help.

Comment: @user3583252 do you remember the point/title of that page so we can search for it? The link is dead and we do not have any clue what was the article about. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am another one stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the page specified in the link above using "Internet Archive", a wonderful project that collect snapshot of older web pages.

A copy of this page it's available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160425124655/https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3531/index.html the copy came from april 2016.

I hope that can be useful for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this on MacOS.  The solution is to create and import an author certificate via Tizen Studio.

Directions for doing this can be found [here](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/setup-sdk/creating-certificates/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Firewall and install certificate manager and app development from tizen update manager

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest link, its for tv but just follow the instruction  and create certificate after that just restart tizen studio. try installing app this time app should get installed now on emulator.
worked for me i  am using wearable 4.0 project and emulator(W-4.0-circle-x86)

https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/setting-up-sdk/creating-certificates

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and RESOLVED.
For me it was just a issue of firewall. So the build could not import external libraries.
I removed the firewall and then clean the project and build. It works now.