# step SDB shell handle failed

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I am trying to develop an application for **Tizen TV** with **SSSP4**. The TV is a **Samsung PM32F-BC**. Once I activate the Debug Mode on the TV and connect the TV with my PC via **Tizen Studio Remote Device Manager**, I create a certificate with Public privileges, build the signed package of the app and get a `.wgt` file. Then I try to deploy the wgt on the TV, but I get this error:

```
step SDB shell handle failed
Failed to `step SDB shell handle 'ls /usr/bin/xwalk-launcher > /tmp/fsgaramella.deployer 2>&1; echo $? ' command` operation
sdb command rejected exception
```

I searched for a solution myself but seems that it is not documented at all. I've found also [this other thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585495/step-sdb-has-failed-error-on-tizen-app-launch) but seems that he found a solution on a link which is broken. 
Any hint for a solution would be apreciated.

Comment: I am also running into this problem. Currently I suspect the emulator image I have is not compatible with the application, possibly due to the version or something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Step SDB has failed error on Tizen App Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585495/step-sdb-has-failed-error-on-tizen-app-launch)

Comment: I explicitly said that my question is similar (or to use your word "duplicated") to the other thread you mentioned. I've also pointed out that in that thread they've found the solution on a link which is broken now. If you check carefully, you could notice that I've commented that thread stating that the link is broken. Thus, I don't know which kind of solution was on that broken link and I still need help finding out the solution for my problem.